# Can this design be made with just CSS?

Tags: html, css, svg

[image] https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDXGI.png - I'm trying to create this design with CSS/HTML. My initial thought, was to create the white "wave" container that wraps the icons with SVG shapes, but I was wondering if you could actually make it with just CSS? How would you guys approach this? :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55276941/can-this-design-be-made-with-just-css

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you do this is using SVG filters: 
[SVG goo on Codepen](https://codepen.io/search/pens?q=goo&page=1&order=popularity&depth=everything)

Also you may like to read this [The Gooey Effect](https://css-tricks.com/gooey-effect/)

The most important is defining a `goo` filter. Next you draw several circles (`border-radius:50%;`) and you apply the svg filter.

The size of the SVG element is irrelevant and you may hide it away.

```css
body{background:skyBlue;}
svg{position:absolute;left:-10em;}
.wrap {
  
  display: block;
  margin:0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 260px;
  position: relative;
  filter:url(#goo);
}
.wrap div {
  
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 90px;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background-color: white;
  color:red;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:80px;

}
.wrap div:nth-child(2){
  left: 90px;
}
.wrap div:nth-child(3){
  left: 180px;
}
```

```html
<svg  width="1" height="1">
<defs>
<filter id="goo">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10" result="blur" />
      <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" 
                     values="1 0 0  0   0  
                             0 1 0  0   0  
                             0 0 1  0   0  
                             0 0 0 40  -10" result="goo"/>
      <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" />
    </filter> 
  </defs>
</svg>


<div class ="wrap">
<div>A</div>
<div>B</div> 
<div>C</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed. What would be the correct way to have more space between the items/elements though - do I need to specify that in the filter or with CSS? :)

Comment: In this case you may want to increase the `stdDeviation` for the `feGaussianBlur` and also increase the alpha alpha value for the `feColorMatrix` (40 in this example). However  if you need those items to be faraway one from each other you would need to consider  drawing it as an SVG shape